# Create a matrix of 0's and 1's from a data frame using R

Tags: r

How can I create a matrix of 0's and 1's from a data set with three columns labelled as hosp (i.e. hospital), pid (i.e. patient id) and treatment, as shown below

```
df<-
structure(list(
hosp=c(1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,2L,2L,2L),
pid=c(1L,1L,1L,2L,3L,3L,4L,5L,5L),
treatment=c(0L,0L,0L,1L,1L,1L,0L,1L,1L)
),
.Names=c("hosp","pid","treatment"),
class="data.frame",row.names=c(NA,-9))
```

The rows and columns of the matrix should be the number of observations (in this case 9) and the unique number of hospitals, respectively. The entries in the matrix should be the treatment values, that is, it is 1 for a given hospital if the corresponding patient received treatment 1 in that hospital and 0 otherwise. The matrix should look like

```
matrix(c(0,0,
0,0,
0,0,
1,0,
1,0,
1,0,
0,0,
0,1,
0,1),nrow=9,byrow=TRUE)
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Create a model matrix from `hosp` as a factor with no intercept term and multiply that by `treatment`:

```
hosp <- factor(df$hosp)
model.matrix(~ hosp + 0) * df$treatment
```

giving:

```
  hosp1 hosp2
1     0     0
2     0     0
3     0     0
4     1     0
5     1     0
6     1     0
7     0     0
8     0     1
9     0     1
attr(,"assign")
[1] 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$hosp
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

**2)**  `outer(hosp, unique(hosp), "==")` is the model matrix of `hosp` except using TRUE/FALSE in place of 1/0.  Multiply that by `treatment`.

```
with(df, outer(hosp, unique(hosp), "==") * treatment)
```

giving

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    0    0
 [2,]    0    0
 [3,]    0    0
 [4,]    1    0
 [5,]    1    0
 [6,]    1    0
 [7,]    0    0
 [8,]    0    1
 [9,]    0    1
```

**Update:** Added (1) and simplified (2).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my workaround for this. Not the cleanest, but it works!

```
    require(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(x = row_number()) %>% 
  select(-pid) %>% 
  spread(x, treatment)

df3 <- df2 %>% 
  gather("keys", "value", 2:10) %>% 
  spread(hosp, value) %>% 
  select(-keys)

df3[is.na(df3)] <- 0
df3 <- as.matrix(df3)
```

**Step by Step:**

Take original `df` and add a row_number to it so we can `spread` without duplication. We'll also remove `pid` since you're changing this to a matrix.

```
    require(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(x = row_number()) %>% 
  select(-pid) %>% 
  spread(x, treatment)
```

Then we want to change it back to long form:

```
df3 <- df2 %>% 
  gather("keys", "value", 2:10) %>% 
  spread(hosp, value) %>% 
  select(-keys)
```

Some of the values are still `NA`, so we convert them into `0`s, and then turn it into a matrix using ``

```
df3[is.na(df3)] <- 0
df3 <- as.matrix(df3)

  1 2
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 1 0
5 1 0
6 1 0
7 0 0
8 0 1
9 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
> sapply(unique(df$hosp),function(x) ifelse(df$hosp==x&df$treatment==1,1,0))
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    0    0
 [2,]    0    0
 [3,]    0    0
 [4,]    1    0
 [5,]    1    0
 [6,]    1    0
 [7,]    0    0
 [8,]    0    1
 [9,]    0    1
```